# display data via ajax when using $_GET

Tags: php, ajax, get

How do I display data based on `$_GET', which is to say without refreshing the page ?

I have this for example, and it shows the correct result whenever I click `add` (increments by 1), but of course it always first refreshes the page.

How do I make it do the same thing without visible page refresh, using ajax?

php and html

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['numbers']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['numbers'];

?>
<br>
<a href="test.php?add" class="add">add</a>

<div id="response"></div>
```

And if for example I wanted to pull something from the database via `post` and print it, I would do something like this:

```
$.post('print_something.php', function(response) {
     $('#response').html(response);
});
```

But how do I change that for get, since there is stuff in the URL plus sessions?

**EDIT:**

I tried this, I removed all php from the current script, added it to `get.php` which is now like this:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $_SESSION['numbers']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['numbers'];
```

And inside my main `index` script I have this:

```
$('a.add').click(function() {
    $.get('get.php', function(response) {
        $('#response').html(response); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now it does not increment each time i click `add`, it just shows `1` the first time and doesn't change afterwards.

Comment: Use $.ajax for the same. It supports both post and get protocols

Comment: To supplement @CodemasterGabriel's comment, see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  You can also use $.get() https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: check for errors, check requests and responses ( e.g. in Chrome Dev Tools panel)

Comment: I use firefox. I see no errors. I clicked 3 times, I see three responses, but each response returns `1`

Comment: Can you reproduce this locally and have a look? All together (minus the html) is like 8 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the `add` parameter to your `$.get`, so `isset($_GET['add'])` is false. Add `add` to your ajax call

```
$.get('get.php', {add:true}, function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response); 
});
```

I put `{add:true}`, but `true` could be anything, as you are only checking if it is set, not the value

alternatively, you could also just add it to your url

```
$.get('get.php?add=true', function(response) {
    $('#response').html(response); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the example code below:

```
$('a.add').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var request = $.ajax({
    url:"get.php", //Please provide the absolute URL to avoid errors.
    type:"GET",
    data:""
    });

    request.done(function(response){
    $("#response").empty().html(response);
    });
});
```